# Get new array of after swapping data in ngfor

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular 4+

Here is my array

i used ngfor to populate data with **draggable** div

```
['MODEL', 'PART', 'CUSTOMER'];
```

what i want whenever i drag/swap one of the div then the new array become something like

```
['PART', 'MODEL', 'CUSTOMER'];
```

cant find any solution for this

my plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/oy2QWJ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update the `html` outside the `scope` of `angular`, you will need to put extra effort to make sure the state of `template/component` are in sync. You should directly update the `model` and as it is 2 way binding, `html` will be rendered automatically according to that.

You need to make following updates

**JS**

- Add private variable `dragIndex`
- Update `drag` function (set dragIndex - index of element being dragged)

  ```
  public drag (index) {
     this.dragIndex = index;
  }
  ```
- Update `drop` function (swap the values in array at the drag and drop indexes)

  ```
  public drop (ev, index: number) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     let temp = this.homePageSearchTiles[this.dragIndex];
     this.homePageSearchTiles[this.dragIndex] = this.homePageSearchTiles[index];
     this.homePageSearchTiles[index] = temp;
     console.log(this.homePageSearchTiles);
  }
  ```

**HTML**

- `i` passed in function was not defined. Define `i` as `index` in `ngFor` and pass it in both `drag` and `drop` functions

  ```
  <div *ngFor="let tiles of homePageSearchTiles; let i = index; (drop)="drop($event, i)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)">
       <div class="tiles ui-g-12 ui-lg-5 card box-id" id="div{{tiles.id}}" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag(i)">
           {{tiles}}
       </div>
  </div>
  ```

Please find working version, [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tw47k8YPCsLXcDTCadvo?p=preview)

Comment: This solution is really amazing.

Comment: event.dataTransfer.setData("src", event.target.id); // you have removed this intentionally which were causing index problem. dont know the internal behaviour of setData but your solution work like a charm

Comment: @mave - Glad to help you :) I had removed the line because it was not required.